# Getting proper locale with SDL on Mac

Tags: c, macos, localization, sdl-2

I am working on a game made with pure C and SDL2, and am considering implementing localisation. Last time I did that in a console application, using C's `<locale.h>` allowed me to do this:

```
#include <locale.h>
sprintf(localeString, "locale: %s", setlocale (LC_ALL, ""));
```

Since the application is ran from a terminal, it reads the `LANG` environment variable, and returns, in my case, `en_GB`.

The problem is, my game is packaged as a `.app` bundle, and can be launched by double clicking the icon in the finder. In that case, since OS X does not pass the environment to GUI apps, the locale returned is `C`.

Is there any way to get the current locale on OS X without using Objective-C?